# Git Log Stat Summary Results Clarification

Tags: git

In the screen below what does 30 ++++ means: 
[image]
<sub>(source: [highoncoding.com](http://www.highoncoding.com/articleimages/git_log_summary.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pluses and minuses are an indication of how many lines were added versus removed.

So in this case it would seem only lines were added to the file.

Comment: So why two "++" instead of one "+". It reads as 30 lines were added (+). What does ++++++++++++ means?

Comment: The number of + and -, I believe, indicates roughly how many lines. Obviously it gets scaled down so that the largest change is a reasonable number of characters.

Comment: Because for the files with two pluses more lines were added than the files with one plus, for many pluses, many lines were added, it's just an indication.

Comment: The number of plus and minus signs are scaled to fit on your screen. So a commit with `++++++` is roughly twice as large as a commit with `+++`.

Comment: This is supposed to be a "histogram", and the pluses (or minuses) make the histogram bars. It's not *really* a histogram though, but it is sort of histogram-like.